# Rounding to the nearest day with Nodatime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm trying to implement a function that calculates the number of days between two date times using nodatime. When it comes to March and daylight savings time I lose a day as the function truncates rather than rounds.

Is there a way to get the Period function to round to the nearest unit rather than truncate? I know I can add 11 hours to the end time and achieve something similar but wondered if there was a native way of doing this in nodatime?

```cs
Period.Between(new LocalDateTime(2020, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0), new LocalDateTime(2020, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0), PeriodUnits.Days).Days
```

Comment: There's no built-in date/time adjuster that does that, no... but could you give more details of the root of the problem? There may well be a cleaner approach to solving *that* issue that only uses built-in code. Notes that `LocalDateTime` has no concept of time zones, so I suspect that anything you do to get the "right" answer with values derived from one time zone will also give the "wrong" answer with values derived from another time zone.

Comment: You could potentially just truncate both values to their dates to start with, but without knowing more about what you're trying to do and where things are going wrong, it's hard to say whether that would work or not.

Comment: It's due to something happening at the same local time each month so that when we lose an hour in March and do my calculation when I do my Period calculation I get one day less than I'm expecting as Period is effectively calculating it as 30 days and 23 hours which I can understand but I'm wanting the ability to round to the nearest day or when I calculate the period be able to get the hours too as if I specify PeriodUnits.Days the hours is 0

Comment: Please edit the question itself to give more details. If you only care about the *date* though, I'd just use `Period.Between(LocalDate, LocalDate, PeriodUnits)` instead - use the `LocalDateTime.Date` property on your start and end. Although if everything really does happen at the same *local* time, you shouldn't lose anything - this is where it would be really helpful to have more context in the question, with concrete examples.

Comment: (Note that 5am and 4am in the sample snippet that's already there are *not* the same local time - so that seems to go against your "at the same local time each month".)

Comment: Any update on this? I'd love to be able to provide an answer for future readers, but I really need more context first.